# Edit not locked for question, leading to multiple rejections

Tags: support

I recently reviewed this question:

[On hover in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423513/on-hover-in-javascript)

It so happened that multiple users were editing the question at the same time(this was unknown to me then).

I tried to add tags of php and html to the question(as it contained php in it). The edit button usually gets locked if another edit is already pending, but it was not in this case, so I submitted this edit. It got rejected, but I didn't know that. Some other user seemed to have made an unrelated edit, so I thought my edit was lost or something, so I resubmitted it. The same thing happened again, leading to three rejected edits in sequence:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4037019/cst1992?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
[image: rejected edits]

Why did this happen? Did I miss something or was it a glitch?

Comment: What does that question have to do with PHP?

Comment: It just contains php code. Well, now I know not to add a tag for that sole reason...

Answer (score 4):

It did not happen entirely because of a conflict, it happened because [a moderator manually rejected your edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11898526) and said why

> This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains

Even if the other rejected instances had not resulted in conflicts, they would (modulo robo-reviewing) have been rejected. The second edit had a user rejection against it too before community stepped in.

Comment: The first two indeed happened because a conflict.

Comment: Mostly, but the second was on its way to rejection by users.